# Use Sublime Text 2 Windows keybindings on a Mac?

Tags: sublime-text-2

I use Sublime Text 2 on Macs and PCs. It would be nice if I could needed to commit only one set of shortcuts to muscle memory. Is there a way to export my Windows bindings and and use them with OS X?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On your Mac:

1. Quit Sublime Text.
2. In Finder (or Terminal, your choice), navigate to ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Default/.
3. Rename "Default (OSX).sublime-keymap" to "Default (OSX old).sublime-keymap", or some other such filename. (Don't delete it in case you want to change it back some day.)
4. Make a duplicate of "Default (Windows).sublime-keymap".
5. Rename the duplicate to "Default (OSX).sublime-keymap". Bear in mind that it's case-sensitive.
6. Relaunch Sublime Text. Now, if you open "Sublime Text 2" > "Preferences" > "Key Bindings - Default" menu item, the listed, default key shortcuts should be the same as for Windows.